# Remove duplicate words from two lists

Tags: bash

Remove duplicate words from the list
example

We have two lists the first list contains `a`

```
a
b
c
d
```

The second list contains `b`

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I want to make a comparison from the first and second list and remove the match from the first and second list so that the result is

```
e
f
```

I created that scirpt

```sh
#!/bin/bash
array_1=()
array_2=()
file1='a'
file2='b'
number1=`wc -l $file2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
number2=`wc -l $file1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`

for i in `cat $file1`
do
    array_1[${#array_1[@]}]="$i"
done
for x in `cat $file2`
do
    array_2[${#array_2[@]}]="$x"
done
for n in $(seq 0 $number1)
do
    for nn in $(seq 0 $number2)
    do
        if [[ ${array_2[$n]} == ${array_1[$nn]} ]]
        then
            echo ${array_2[$n]}
        fi
    done
done
```

I have created this script, but in trying to remove matched words, I have some difficulties using inequality where the result is wrong.
Because once word checks if the character is in array and if it exists then it will be printed
This is the opposite of what I want

If I use equality, then the result will be the opposite of what I want, because the result will be
Matching words in the two texts and non-matching will be removed

Comment: `comm` and `sort` are your friends.

Comment: If you are doing this for education fine, but are you aware of the `comm` utility? It can perform this task on sorted data files, something like `comm -13 f1 f2` will yield that output. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter  Thank you
I had no knowledge of that tool
It looks like a good thing

Comment: what happens if file `a` also contains the letters `x` and `y`? should the final output be `e,f,x,y` (ie, letters that only exist in one file) or should the final output remain `e,f` (ie, letters that only exist in file `b`)?

Comment: `grep -vf a b`?

Comment: I don't want to print anything from the file a
I just want to use it for comparison
If a word in file b is in file a
It is not printed
If a word in File B is not present in File A it is printed

Comment: if you want to continue with a solution that uses arrays: a) first populate the array with letters from file `b`, b) loop through letters from file `a` and if the letter exists in the array then `unset` that array element (ie, remove from array), c) what's left in the array is a list of characters that only exist in file `b` ; doable in `bash` but a bit easier if done in `awk`

Comment: Looks like a good idea, work on it now

Comment: consider using an associative array (ie, the letters act as the array indices); this will simplify the logic a bit; `typeset -A array` ... `array[${ltrB}]=''` ... `unset array[${ltrA}]` ... `for ltr in ${!array[@]}; do echo "${ltr}"; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script works as indicated markp-fuso Thank you for my help

First, it puts the file's values in array
Then it checks for compatibility
If the characters are in file b and they are in file a then it will remove the value from array
If not, leave it in array as it goes

I thank `markp-fuso`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
array_1=()
array_2=()
file1='a'
file2='b'

for i in `cat $file1`
do
    array_1+=($i)
done

for x in `cat $file2`
do
    array_2+=($x)
done

for i in `seq 0 ${#array_2[@]}`
do
    for x in `seq 0 ${#array_1[@]}`
    do
        if [[ ${array_2[$i]} == ${array_1[$x]} ]]
        then
            unset 'array_2[$i]'
        fi
    done
done
for line in "${array_2[@]}"
do
    echo $line
done
```